# Why does Typescript Union + Mapped Types work differently with and without Generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am new to using generics. The following code has different "w0" and "w1", but the code looks the same.

Why they are different, and how I can get the opposite type in the opposite way.

I've looked through some documents but I can't find any explanation, is there any document that can explain the principle of their different types?

How can I get `Calc<BaseA> | Calc<BaseB>` with out `Calc` and `Generics`.

How can I get `{ type: "A" | "B"; flag: number; }` with `Generics`.

```js
type BaseA = {
  type: 'A'
  name: string
  flag: number
}

type BaseB = {
  type: 'B'
  id: number
  flag: number
}

type Base = BaseA | BaseB

type w0 = {
  [k in keyof Base]: Base[k]
}
/*
w0 = {
  type: "A" | "B";
  flag: number;
}
*/
type Calc<W> = {
  [k in keyof W]: W[k]
}
type w1 = Calc<Base>
/*
w1 = Calc<BaseA> | Calc<BaseB>
*/
type z0 = Exclude<w0,BaseA>
// z0 = w0
type z1 = Exclude<w1,BaseA>
// z1 = BaseB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is easy to solve:

```
type Q1 = {
  [B in Base as B["type"]]: {
    [K2 in keyof B]: B[K2]
  }
}[Base["type"]]

// type Q1 = {
//     type: 'A';
//     name: string;
//     flag: number;
// } | {
//     type: 'B';
//     id: number;
//     flag: number;
// }
```

We first map over each element in `Base` and take the `type` key as the key for the resulting type. For each element, we can map over the keys of the element. In the end, we index this type with `Base["type"]` to get the union.

You could now replace the inner map with `Calc`.

```
type Q1 = {
  [B in Base as B["type"]]: Calc<B>
}[Base["type"]]

// type Q1 = Calc<BaseA> | Calc<BaseB>
```

---

The second problem is a bit trickier. It is caused by [Distributive Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). I found that distributivity could only be disabled with this trick:

```
type Calc2<W extends [any]> = {
  [k in keyof W[0]]: W[0][k] 
}

type Q2 = Calc2<[Base]>

// type Q2 = {
//     type: "A" | "B";
//     flag: number;
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=45&ssc=5&pln=42&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgQSgXigbwFBSqSALigHJkTcoA7OAWwmIWACcBLKgc0oDMAbODsSoBXWgCMIzbAF9s2AtHhIY6LJQXESMCnlYATIaIlS8fAYfGSZchbETQMSlFAA%20d5XM%202AigEZVOHgA2irs7tCIsEEARArRALrxxIF4UEEA0gBMUGEA1hAgAPbcsElRWfGUstIh9jFxiXIA9E344NB%20AdgtqXgapOQA3N2tvTT0jCzsHMM9vWaC1EaSs63Srmpzqf1aJKu9OQZLlsz78-yLIif7sl7tUADCcLwAxpkAPADqUBAAHsAQKh6BBpOBUEDxAB8XWCuRyVCg%20SKJU%20QQADIliKiMUFcvEoNZ5PdvNkME9Xh9akgoc1Wj5SZtRtt2sRoshohtojBomdUgsLMYbkA)

Comment: Thanks, "Distributive Conditional Types" is what I was looking for, but I didn't know the term before and missed this subsection.